# private value dbConfig escapes its defining scope as part of type Repository.this.dbConfig.driver.api.Query[T,E,S]

Tags: playframework, slick, slick-3.0

```
implicit class QueryExtensions[T, E, S[E]](val q: Query[T, E, S]) {
  def page(no: Int, pageSize: Int): Query[T, E, S] = {
    q.drop((no - 1) * pageSize).take(pageSize)
  }
}
```

When trying to use this code for pagination of slick in playframework I get the following error:

```
private value dbConfig escapes its defining scope as part of typeRepository.this.dbConfig.driver.api.Query[T,E,S]
```

What can I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I had dbConfig defined has private and has now understand the QueryExtensions needed to access this value and couldn't. I changed the private to protected and solved the issue.